# Naming convention of variables in C# programming language

Tags: c#, coding-standards, variables, conventions

I'm watching a video on C# about Variables. The author declares a variable inside a method and he named it like this: string MyName ="James";

my question is: which convention is recommended by .Net Framework. Is it Pascal casing as in the above example or is it camel case?

Comment: The problem with this question, which you didn't know so it's not your fault, is that there is in fact no canonical convention for C#. There are common conventions; unfortunately more than one, but it would be quite difficult for you to get an answer here that's anything but pure opinion. Sorry, voting to close; my suggestion: Spend some time reading code in popular github and codeplex repositories to see what conventions they use as the people who write most of the popular ones are industry-experienced folks, and as canonical to what's common as you'll find.

Comment: Naming conventions from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Yusubov These describe naming of the public parts of libraries, not local variables.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think there's something like an 'official' convention. As far as I know, the following is considered good practice by many  experienced C# developers:

`PascalCase for public member variables (string MyName = "James")`

`camelCase for local variables (string myName = "James")`

`_leadingUnderscore for private member variables (string _myName = "James")`

With this approach, one can distinguish between local variables as well as public and private members by the case of their first letter.

As with any coding convention, this is also subject to personal preferences. Therefore, there is no definite answer. A general goal should be to keep the code as readable and comprehensible as possible.

Comment: +1 This is close to the style I've seen. I believe it's generally taken from the style used in MSDN's examples. Usually I see properties getting `PascalCase`, locals getting `camelCase`, and private members getting a `_leadingUnderscore`.

Comment: Do you mean Fields or Properties when you said member variables?

Comment: Delphi developers tend to name function/method parameters by prefixing them with an 'a': `(aParameter: string)`. I realize parameters are essentially local variables, especially when passed by value, but it is often very helpful to "see" that a var is actually passed in as a parameter. Is there any such convention in C#?

Comment: And another one: member fields. Delphians prefix them with an 'F'. I have seen C# code that declares them with an underscore: `private string _SomeString`. Would you say that is a convention? (Just dipping my toes in C# and wondering about this stuff).

Comment: @Kaser fields and properties aren't distinguished by casing, the indicators in naming on C# are about scope; which means everywhere (member public), class-only (member private), and method-only (local).

Comment: @KChaloux and Jimmy Hoffa: Thanks for pointing out the leading underscore convention. I added it to the answer.

Comment: The convention _leadingUnerscore is coming from C++ language

Comment: This is inaccurate. There are published naming conventions for public members (and public classes etc.).

Comment: The other thing to consider is how your variables and methods will appear in Code Completion in the IDE. If you have prefixed local variables, private class, etc, then you can print you prefix, call the Code Completion and see all variables of the group. Though, more powerful tools like ReSharper, can order and color you variables in CC for you to distinguish.

Comment: Why can't you just keep it simple, like us Javartians.

Answer (score 7):

The .Net Framework Naming Conventions ([v4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), [v1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) are agnostic about this.  *They do not specify a standard for naming local variables.*  You'll have to decide on your own convention for naming these.

I personally use camelCase, and disambiguate member variables from parameter names with `this` when necessary.  But leading underscores (i.e. `_memberVariable`) are also valid.

Comment: This is exactly the reason of using naming conventions - using `this` to distinguish local variables from fields/properties. 5 additional letters every time is too much imho.